# Separating test and core project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I already found this post: [Separating tests from src with Maven Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517351/seperating-tests-from-src-with-maven-project).

> I've just started working on a Java project (as I usually use .net), and one of the first > things that strikes me as odd is that in the Maven project there is a /src and a /test 
>   directory where obviously the source code and the tests should go.
>
> In .net I preferred to have the tests in a separate assembly/project, so for example I 
>   would have:
>
> MyProject
>   MyProject.Tests
>   That way I dont have to bloat my deployed code with any tests and it makes it easier to 
>   test my code in true isolation and in alot of cases I didnt bother writing tests per 
>   project, I would just have solution wide unit/integration/acceptance tests i.e 
>   MySolution.UnitTests, MySolution.IntegrationTests.
>
> However in Java it just seems to be bundled together, and I would rather separate it out, > however I hear that Maven is a cruel mistress when you want to do things differently to 
>   the default structures.
>
> So to reign this post back in, my main [question is]:
>
> Is there a way to separate out the tests from the project **[How?]**

Although this question exactly describes what I try to achieve, the thread has not provided the solution for how to do it.

I'd like to know whether there is a way to have a separate project just for (unit) testing with JUnit. I want to have the actual source code in a "core" project and the according tests in a separate "test" project instead of having one single project with src/main and src/test paths.
However, I don't know how to configure the (parent) pom.xml files to achieve that.

So far, I defined a parent pom that declares the two projects as modules. In addition, for each of the two projects, I have a separate pom file declaring the required dependencies etc. Of course, the pom file of the test project defines the core project as a dependency.

I guess I have to configure the pom file of the core project to tell the testing plugin to look in the other project for the tests. But how should such behaviour be configured?

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it in pretty much the same way. I declared modules of several projects and my test project was the last one on the module list. None of the other projects contain tests. So when I run `mvn clean install` it compiles all the code and runs the tests in the `test` project at the end. No special configuration is needed to achieve that. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: @DeepakBala I already did exactly what you are supposing. But I get lots of error logs telling me all the same, namely that classes cannot be found, like "package org.junit does not exist". But I referenced the source project.

Comment: Where are these tests written exactly ? On the `src/tests` folder ? Do you have `org.junit` under the `test` scope in your pom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the Maven conventions (having both the src and test folders) you will have an easier time.  Your tests will not be deployed along with your compiled source so I wouldn't worry about bloat.  Maven will compile both a jar and a test jar file (assuming you're using jars).  If you really want separate src/test modules then yes, the multi-module approach with a common parent is the way to go. The test module would have a dependency on the source module but not the other way around.  Really this just amounts to reinventing what Maven is already doing for you though.

In the long run, I think you'd be happier using the conventional approach though as things will go a lot smoother.

Comment: I'd add that IDE support generally assumes that you're going to have the test sources in the same project as the production source, and that you're following the maven standards. You're really making a rod for your own back by trying to port .net ideas into the java world -- they're different for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do not pay attention to the naysayers who will try to convince you that you have to do it in one of the established ways or else you will run into trouble. This is cargo cult engineering, and it reflects the cowardice of your average enterprise employee out there, who will rather die than try something different or think outside the box for a moment.

It is perfectly doable to have a huge multi-module maven project, with loads of tests, where not a single module contains both production and test subfolders, and instead every single module is either production, or test. That's the only way they do it in the DotNet world, and I never heard anyone complaining.

There exist situations where you absolutely have to split your modules this way, so maven has no option but to support this. Such situations arise when the dependencies are such that the tests of module A depend on module B which in turn depends on the production code of model A. If both the tests and production code of module A are in the same actual module, this causes a circular dependency, so the project is unbuildable. Such an arrangement is not commonplace, but it does happen some times. When it happens, you have to move the tests of A into a separate module C, which depends on both A and B, and leave only production code on A.

In maven, there is nothing special to it: in production modules you only specify `<sourceDirectory>`, while in test modules you only specify `<testSourceDirectory>`. Everything else is done as expected: Both modules have the same parent pom, and the parent pom references them both. JUnit and other test-related dependencies are only included by the test modules. It is so straightforward that it is trivial. (I am not sure what kind of trouble the OP was facing that made him ask the question.)

As a matter of fact, if it was not for the particular maven plugins that people use for running tests during continuous deployment, you would not even need `<testSourceDirectory>`, you could be using in all modules nothing but `<sourceDirectory>`. IntelliJ IDEA does not have a problem detecting and running tests even if they are under `<sourceDirectory>`, but the maven surefire plugin does expect tests to be under `<testSourceDirectory>`, so you have to use `<testSourceDirectory>` just to keep that plugin happy.

My personal opinion is that supporting a distinction between production and test subfolders within the same module adds a mind-boggling amount of completely unnecessary complication to build systems. The entire java world would be doing just fine if the feature did not exist at all. Of course this opinion is tentative, since unbeknownst to me there may exist important reasons due to which this distinction is useful. If anyone knows of any such reasons, please enlighten me in the comments.